# Object Factory and this Pointer

Tags: c++, this, factory

I want to understand a simple **object factory** like this.

```
template <class Base>
class Factory
{
protected:
Factory (std::string name)
...
}
Factory<Base>::Factory (std::string name)
{
        Factory_Map[name] = this;
}
//-------------------------------------
template <class Derived, class Base>
class Factory_Der: public Factory<Base>
{
public:
Factory_Der(std::string name) : Factory<Base>(name) { }
...
};
```

So the constructor of **Factory_Der** will call the constructor of **Factory**. But I don't know **this** pointer in constructor of **Factory** will refer to **Factory** object or **Factory_Der** object. It seems that **this** will refer to **Factory** object but then the code shouldn't work! (and it is working).

Thanks

Comment: Because Factory_Der derives from Factory, that means a Factory_Der object is a Factory object.

Comment: I think that "this" pointer should refer to the object of class and since it is insider constructor of Factory class it will point to Factory Object. i.e. if "this" pointer was inside constructor of Factory_Der class it was pointing to Factory_Der. Isn't it?

Comment: It still isn't clear why you think it wouldn't work.  What specifically wouldn't work?

Comment: Let me ask this way. When a class derived from base class, is it like constructor of Base copied to derived class (copying the commands). i.e. "this" pointer in the constructor of Base class. I'm not sure how system handles {ctor Derived : Base(arguments)}. Does it copy ctor of Base to Derived's ctor? or run it?

Comment: Not really. You can use the public base class methods on an object of the derived class, but there's really no copying involved.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So why "this" pointer here refers to Derived class? I don't understand the logic of "this" pointer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you created one object, a `Factory_Der` object, right? So when you ask, what object does the `this` pointer point to, well, what object *can* it point to? You just have one object -- a `Factory_Der` object.

Since `Factory_Der` inherits from `Factory`, part of the memory layout of a `Factory_Der` object can be viewed as a `Factory` object. But it's part of the *same object*. There is no "separate" `Factory` object anywhere that it could be pointing to.

You seemed to get caught up in the fact that these are constructors. But constructors work very much like methods, except that they are special in that they are "automatically called" during object construction after the memory allocation. You could imagine that this object construction:

```
Factory_Der *foo = new Factory_Der;
```

translates underneath into something like this (not real syntax; this is how Objective-C does it however):

```
Factory_Der *foo = malloc(sizeof(Factory_Der));
foo->constructor();
```

This explains why `this` in the constructor points to the object.

At the beginning of every constructor, one can specify an optional initializer list, which specifies how to initialize the base classes and the fields. (If you skip the initializer for something, a default is chosen.) So basically, a constructor automatically calls the constructor of the super class at the very beginning.

So again, we can imagine that your constructor:

```
Factory_Der(std::string name) : Factory<Base>(name) { }
```

gets translated underneath into something like this:

```
void constructor(std::string name) { this->Factory<Base>::constructor(name); }
```

So you see, the derived class's constructor essentially "passes" its `this` to the base class's constructor. So the object that they see from `this` is the *same object*.

Of course, at the time the base class's constructor is running, the derived class's state is not set up. So whether the object can be truly considered a derived class object is a matter of debate. But if your question is whether the object that `Factory`'s constructor sees from `this` is the object that will eventually become a `Factory_Der` object, then the answer is unequivocally yes.

Comment: In fact, using `this` inside the base class constructor is dangerous, since the derived object does not yet exist. This can lead to trouble in case of multiple inheritance or a virtual class inheriting from a non-virtual one (the later not being a good practice for other reasons, anyway).

Comment: @Gorpik: yea but in this case he is not calling any methods on it. He is just storing the pointer for later use

Comment: What I mean is that the address of the `this` pointer may not be the real address of the object in the cases I mentioned. I may be wrong, but I think we are running into undefined behaviour (only in these cases, let me remark).

Comment: @Gorpik: hmm, I haven't investigated the standard in detail, but my intuition tells me that: The `this` pointer in the base class constructor should the `this` pointer in the derived class constructor converted to base class pointer type. Yes, this may not be the same address as the `this` pointer in the derived class, due to cases like virtual inheritance or something. But since he is storing it in `Factory_Map`, which presumably is a map of `Factory *`, isn't that exactly what he wants anyway (the pointer to the base class type)?

Answer (score 0):

Your logical problem is that you think that a `Factory*` is restricted to be pointing to a `Factory` object. Although such a pointer is restricted to be pointing to a `Factory` or any of its subclasses(as they are `Factory`s). In this case `this` is pointing to the real instantiated object which is indeed of type `Factory_Der`. You should really reread inheritance as it seems to me that you havent fully understood it.

Comment: I know base pointer can be used to point to derived classes. But I think that "this" pointer should refer to the object of class which called that method and since it is inside of constructor of Factory class it will point to Factory Object. i.e. if "this" pointer was inside constructor of Factory_Der class it was pointing to Factory_Der.